# Protect web application from fishing

Tags: angularjs, caching, html

The following are my concerns on my webpage

- How to disable the user from viewing my web-page cache?
- How to protect user from viewing my source code and the variable (even they can put breakpoint to debug or hack)
- I saw FaceBook not allowing user to view FB page as developer / inspect. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can never prevent anyone from reading the html/js/css which is sent to the browser. The only methods are security by obscurity, that is, make it harder but if someone wants to see it they will.

- Minify your JS, HTML and CSS code.
- Use tricks like   to prevent right click -> view source.

I just checked Facebook and there is no prevention of reading their source code. They just output a message in their console log to inform people to not paste script code.

Also, hiding source code has nothing to do with Fishing. With Fishing someone copy your website and trick people to go there.